# Parallel port recording to file on Win XP

Tags: parallel-port

I need to write a simple program that records all the input from parallel port into a file. Data flows from industrial machine, setup is fairly simple, but I can't find any good open source examples on parallel port reading for Windows.

Do you know a software that does this (and lets me learn how to do it myself), or is there any guideline for parallel port programming on XP?

Thanks.

Comment: On note I missed, language I know is C/C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows doesn't have services for low-level access to the parallel port signals. I am afraid you have to write a device driver (kernel programming...). The good news is that many people have already done it, example [here](http://www.beyondlogic.org/porttalk/porttalk.htm) (NOTE: I haven't tested this particular product).

Regards